# JavaScript function multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a javascript function that when the button is clicked it gets the content of the page, displays the text, and then fades it out. But, when it is clicked a second time, the text doesn't appear.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$("input[name=buttonup4206]").click(function(){
  $.ajax({url:"vote.php", success:function(result){
    $("#up4206").html(result);
    setTimeout(function(){$("#up4206").fadeOut('slow');},2000);
 }});
});});
</script>
<input type="image" name="buttonup4206" id="buttonup4206" src="vote.png"></input>
<div id="up4206"></div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Once faded out, your element has `display: none`, so change this line to:

```
$("#up4206").css('display', 'block').html(result);
```

Comment: @MarcelGwerder It is pretty much the same thing.

Comment: @elclanrs You got me, I didn't think about that!

Comment: @MarcelGwerder if you want to use `display:block` use `.show()`, else use `.css('display')`.